# BS4 Iterate over table elements nextsibling or parent?

Tags: beautifulsoup, nextsibling

I am trying to pull all of the text and links by date in a table and so far can only get one entry (but not correctly as the link is not named correctly).  I think `nextsibling` might work here but perhaps that's not the right solution.

Here's the html:

```html
<ul class="indented">
  <br>
  <strong>May 15, 2019</strong>
  <ul>
    Sign up for more insight into FERC with our monthly news email, The FERC insight
    <a href="/media/insight.asp">Read More</a>
  </ul>
  <br><br>
  <strong>May 15, 2019</strong>
  <ul>
    FERC To Convene a Technical Conference regarding Columbia Gas Transmission, LLC on July 10, 2019
    <a href="/CalendarFiles/20190515104556-RP19-763-000%20TC.pdf">Notice</a> <img src="/images/icon_pdf.gif" alt="PDF"> | <a href="/EventCalendar/EventDetails.aspx?ID=13414&amp;CalType=%20&amp;CalendarID=116&amp;Date=07/10/2019&amp;View=Listview">Event Details</a>
  </ul>
  <br><br>
```

Here's my code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url1 = ('https://www.ferc.gov/media/headlines.asp')
r = requests.get(url1)
# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')


# Pull headline  text from the ul class indented

headlines = soup.find_all("ul", class_="indented")
headline = headlines[0]

date  = headline.select_one('strong').text.strip()

print(date)

headline_text = headline.select_one('ul').text.strip()
print(headline_text)

headline_link = headline.select_one('ul a')["href"]
headline_link = 'https://www.ferc.gov' + headline_link 
print(headline_link)
```

I get the first date, text and link because I'm using `select_one`.  I need to get all of the links and name them properly for each date. Would `findnext` work here or `findnextsibling`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for; it gets the date, announcement and related links:

```
[start same as your code; thru soup declaration]

dates = soup.find_all("strong")
for date in dates:
    if '2019' in date.text:        
        print(date.text)
        print(date.nextSibling.nextSibling.text)
        for ref in date.nextSibling.nextSibling.find_all('a'):
            new_link = "https://www.ferc.gov" + ref['href']
            print(new_link)
    print('=============================')
```

Random part of the output:

```
May 15, 2019

            FERC To Convene a Technical Conference regarding Columbia Gas Transmission, LLC on July 10, 2019
Notice   

| Event Details

https://www.ferc.gov/CalendarFiles/20190515104556-RP19-763-000%20TC.pdf
https://www.ferc.gov/EventCalendar/EventDetails.aspx?ID=13414&CalType=%20&CalendarID=116&Date=07/10/2019&View=Listview
=============================
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I would like to not have to update the code each year (in case on January 1 I forget to do it).  I found the info available via rss so I am rewriting the code for that.  Thanks